# How can I remove a parameter from a subclass constructor in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, parameters, constructor

In my superclass, I have defined the parameters a, b, c and d. For its subclass, I want to remove d. Is there any way for me to do this?

```java
abstract class Prescription {
    protected Medicine Medicine;
    protected Doctor doctor;
    protected int patientID, thing;
    public Resept(Medicine medicine, Doctor doctor, int patientID, int thing) {
        this.legemiddel = legemiddel;
        this.lege = utskrivendeLege;
        this.pasientID = pasientID;
        this.thing = thing;
```

And in my subclass, I would like to create a constructor without the last parameter "thing"

```java
public class TypeBPrescription extends Prescription {
    public TypeBPresciption(Medicine medicine, Doctor doctor, int patientID){
        super(Medicine medicine, Doctor doctor, int patientID,)
    }
}
```

Writing it like this gives me the error that the constructor in the subclass TypeBPrescription is undefined. I want the subclass to not have "thing", but I want my superclass to have it. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If a `TypeBPrescription` is a `Prescription` and `Prescription` has a `thing` then `TypeBPrescription` must also have a `thing`. Because it is a `Prescription`. Make it an `Option` type or `null`. You could also make `thing` `private`. But if there's a way to access `thing` from `Prescription` than it will still be visible.

Comment: _but I want my superclass to have it_ Why would the superclass have `thing` if it does not have meaning to all sub-classes?  How will this make sense to the next person that needs to create a sub-class?  At least create an overloaded constructor in the superclass which does not require `thing` (to clarify that `thing` is optional).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add multiple constructors to the super to clarify `thing` is optional:

```
abstract class Prescription {
    private static final int DEFAULT_THING = 0;
    protected Medicine Medicine;
    protected Doctor doctor;
    protected int patientID, thing;

    public Prescription (Medicine medicine, Doctor doctor, int patientID) 
   {
    this(medicine, doctor, paitentId, DEFAULT_THING);


    public Prescription (Medicine medicine, Doctor doctor, int patientID, int thing) {
    this.legemiddel = legemiddel;
    this.lege = utskrivendeLege;
    this.pasientID = pasientID;
    this.thing = thing;
}
```

Then a sub-class can use whichever constructor fits their context.

Comment: Thanks man! I read your comments above, and you're right: I should have added more details in asking the question. I'm supposed to create other subclasses that inherit all the parameters, but this particular one does not inherit the last one. I'm fairly new to Java, so I didn't know about overloading constructors until now!

Answer (score 2):

I would pass a default value to the super class.

```
public TypeBPresciption(Medicine medicine, Doctor doctor, int patientID){
    super(medicine, doctor, patientID, 0)
}
```

Comment: I didn't pay attention.  I just copied and pasted the original code.  But you are right, the code won't compile.  I removed the types.

Comment: I disagree with this approach as it would require all sub-classes to somehow know to pass 0 as the default value.  Instead, the superclass should have an overloaded constructor.

Comment: How would you do it if the super class is written by someone else and you can't change it?

Comment: I supposed get back with the original author and ask for documentation/clarification.  (But in this case, the first few words of the question: _In my superclass..._ so OP has control.)

Comment: Thanks! Assuming that the super class was written by somebody else: What would "0" do exactly?